# Cypress HTML log is terrible at indicating cy.get() DOM element names, is there any solution/workaround?

Tags: testing, logging, mocha.js, cypress, mochawesome

If I have the cypress code:

```
cy.get('[testid="cancel-button"]').should('not.exist')
cy.get('[testid="reset-button"]').should('not.exist')
cy.get('[testid="other-button"]').should('not.exist')
```

of course in `cypress open` I can see the `cy.get(XXX)` criteria (in my case, the testid attribute) in the log, but for `cypress run` the HTML log only outputs:

```
Expected <button.bp3-button> not to exist in the DOM, but it was continuously found.
```

How is this helpful at all? I will have no way of knowing which one failed because all I see is `<button.bp3-button>`. I want to see the testid attribute in the `cy.get()` call.  Is there any way to get the `cy.get(XXX)` criteria to be where `<button.bp3-button>` is in the failure log?

Comment: I think the log is pretty clear, it says the element `<button.bp3-button>` was supposed to not exist, but cypress found it. Also with the error message, cypress points to the line of code where the error occurred. Can you elaborate a bit, what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I will edit the code in my question to better outline why this is a problem